# how to keep the current location dot on the centre of the map when moving, google map, swift

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my project I am using google map. I am enabling the current location dot like this:

```
 self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

After that I am getting the current location latitude and longitude like this:

```
 guard let currentLat = self.mapView?.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude,
          let currentLan = self.mapView?.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else {
          showMessageFail(title: "Fail", myMessage: "Could not determine your current location")
          return
        }
```

And then focusing the camera on current location like this:

```
  let currentPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLan)
  self.mapView?.animate(toLocation: self.currentPosition)
```

Everything is perfectly fine, now it shows the current location dot (the blue dot on google map) on the centre of the map. Now when current location changed, say I am in a car the current location dot moves, at some point it moves out of the bounds of the map. How can I always keep the current location dot on the centre of the map and move the map not the dot. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

currLocation = manager.location!

```
    let locationOfDevice: CLLocation = currLocation // this determines the location of the device using the users location

    let deviceCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationOfDevice.coordinate // determines the coordinates of the device using the location device variabel which has in it the user location.

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1) // this determines the span in which its determined that 1 degree is 69 miles.

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: deviceCoordinate, span: span) // set the center equal to the device coordinates and the span equal to the span variable we have created this will give you the region.

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true);
```

Comment: I am using google map not mapKit, you sure its gonna work ?

Comment: this is for apple map

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocation *newMyLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude  longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];



                         _cmarker.position = newMyLocation.coordinate;

                         CGPoint point1 =[_mapkitView.projection pointForCoordinate:newMyLocation.coordinate];

                         point1.y = -400;

                         GMSCameraUpdate *cameraUpdate = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:[_mapkitView.projection coordinateForPoint:point1]];
                         [_mapkitView animateWithCameraUpdate:cameraUpdate];
                         _cmarker.map = self.mapkitView;



                         //[_mapkitView setCenterCoordinate:newMyLocation.coordinate zoomLevel:_mapkitView.zoomLevel animated:YES];

                         [_mapkitView animateToLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newMyLocation.coordinate.latitude, newMyLocation.coordinate.longitude)];
                         [_mapkitView animateToZoom:_mapkitView.camera.zoom]; // animate to that zoom level
```

Comment: I am using swift as you can clearly see and **locationManager** dosent solve the issue which I have stated above.

Comment: use above code in didupdate user location delegate of cllocation manager and enable speed check

Comment: Ok I will convert it check in the morning, will let you know.

Comment: I have a code to move map with user location but is in objective c

Comment: use this to move map :

Comment: GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:_currentNewLocation.coordinate zoom:_mapkitView.camera.zoom bearing:manager.location.course viewingAngle:self.mapkitView.camera.viewingAngle];
                [_mapkitView animateToCameraPosition:camera];